# Multiple location Pins in Subsampling Scale Image View

Tags: android

I have a demo app in which I have used [SubsamplingScaleImageView](https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view/) from Dave Morrissey.
Basically I have a large image which serves as a map, and I need the zoom and pan functionality.

I also need pins on the map. I used [PinView](https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view/blob/master/sample/src/com/davemorrissey/labs/subscaleview/sample/extension/views/PinView.java) from the above library to display pins. But I only achieved to display one pin. I have the following code:

```
mapView.setPin(new PointF(460f, 320f));
mapView.setPin(new PointF(320f, 460f));
```

The problem is only the second pin is shown.. If I add multiple pins, only the last one is shown.
I need to display multiple pins at once.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: can you save image with it's pins? how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Pin variable is defined as `global  ( private Bitmap pin; )`

==> One instance of Pinview is associated with a single "Bitmap pin"

You could :

- modify the `PinView` class in order to associate it with a array of `{Bitmap pin, PointF sPin}`
- instantiate a local Bitmap Pin in `setPin` method and put it with `sPin` in the array

Comment: Thank you, I already did the first method, with the array of pins, and magically, it works!